# Moving on from Merb - where can I find a home?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, merb

I moved my application off of Rails early in 2009 because I didn't need or want all of the features in that framework (ORM, MVC etc) and didn't like the large footprint we were generating (200Mb). Merb-core has been a great home for our application but I'm now wondering if we should move elsewhere now that Merb & Rails have merged.

Does anyone have advice on the following questions?

- Should we stay on Merb?
- Given the desire for a minimal
  footprint, is there any point trying
  to reimplement the app on Rails 3.x?
- I have some experience with thin and
  Rack but use enough Merb features
  that the port wouldn't be painless -
  is it worth going 'down' to bare
  Rack?

Thanks, I appreciate that some of these are subjective but I hope that there are enough people who have used Merb and who have faced the same questions.

Just as an aside, the last question here about Merb was almost four months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of production apps running with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). It's light-weight and generally a pleasure to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (points awarded). I've heard good things about Sinatra. Have you worked with Merb at all? Any comments on how similar the frameworks are.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I'd go into more detail, but I never used Merb directly. Rails and Sinatra mainly.

Answer (score 1):

Since Rails 3.x is more modular than before, you might want to have a look at it too. You can slim it down quite far. If you're going for a really minimal footprint, Sinatra is an excellent choice.

Comment: Thanks iain. I'm probably going to take a closer look at Sinatra first. Points awarded for taking the time to answer and the Sinatra recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Does Merb not meet your needs anymore?  I'm still using it.  I've tried Rails 3 and it doesn't feel at all like the "Merb 2" I was promised; kind of just feels like Rails.  As such I continue to use Merb for new projects.  I have one I deployed this past summer and a larger project for an existing website that I am currently developing.  Perhaps it's not a very popular framework, but it meets most of my goals and so far I've seen no reason to leave it behind.

Comment: +1 for having tried Rails and still going back to Merb. Any chance you could expand a little more on why Rails 3 isn't Merb 2 as promised?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I guess I missed this response.  I don't feel like Rails 3 compares to Merb in terms of speed, modularity, or being lightweight.  I also prefer Merb's API, but that's highly subjective.  At the end of the day I can't see what I need out of Rails that I can't get done just as easily with Merb.  Merb's future development is a bit worrying and it is a bit stagnant, but its still very feature-complete and gets the job done.  Padrino is also a very nice framework that I find is comparable to Merb; if you want a very actively developed framework you can try that as well.